# if $p \mid (a^2 + b^2 )$, $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$. Prove that there exists an integer $c$ such that $c^2 \equiv −1 \mod p$.

Tags: divisibility, congruences

Given $p$ is prime, I'm not really sure what im supposed to do with the information that $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$ in order to conclude $c^2 \equiv −1 \mod p$.

Comment: Off of the top of my head I believe there is a theorem of fermat that has to do with the conditions an integer need to satisfy to be represented as a sum of squares.

Answer (score 2):

If $p \nmid a$, there is such $c$ that $ca\equiv b \mod{p}$. Then $a^2(c^2+1)=(ac)^2+a^2\equiv b^2+a^2 \mod{p}$. So $p\mid a^2(c^2+1)$ what implies $p\mid (c^2+1)$

Comment: If p∤a, there is such c that ca≡b. Can you explain this part to me?

Comment: You can look on numbers $d_k=ka$ ($k=0,1,\ldots p-1$). Obviously, if $k\neq l$, $p\nmid d_k-d_l$. So, $\{d_0,\ldots , d_{p-1}\}$ are different reminders modulo p. There are $p$ of them, so they are all different reminders, which means there is such $c$ that $d_c=ca\equiv b$